# Rewriting paths with undertow-handlers.conf doesn't work as expected

Tags: jboss7.x, angular-router, undertow

## Background

JBoss 7.1.5 EAP back-end with an Angular 7 UI.

I need to make JBoss aware of the UI's routes, but rewrite them all to the UI's index page for routing by Angular.

The project is structured thus:

```
webapp/
  WEB-INF/
    undertow-handlers.conf
    web.xml
    ...etc
  login/
    background.jpg
  login.jsp
  index.jsp

  assets/*
  ...html
  ...js
  ...css
```

`index.jsp` simply `response.sendRedirect("index.html")`s, where index.html is part of the assets produced by the Angular CLI. JavaScript and HTML is served from `webapp/`, images from `webapp/assets/`.

## Configuration

From `standalone-full.xml`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost,workstation">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="request-dumper"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config x-powered-by="false"/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <filter name="request-dumper" module="io.undertow.core" class-name="io.undertow.server.handlers.RequestDumpingHandler"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

and

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="workstation"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

With the above configuration, I see the expected server log:

```
[org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/' for server 'default-server'
```

And I can access the site's login page, and the URI `/` serves the main angular index page and assets as expected.

## Problem

What I need is for paths in this context (like `/base` or `/shop/60`) to be handled by Angular, so redirected to index.

As a simple test based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978074/how-do-i-configure-undertow-handlers-to-support-proper-rewriting-for-spa-bookmar), I have tried this single rule in `WEB-INF/undertow-handlers.conf`:

```
exists(%{RELATIVE_PATH}) -> done
path-prefix('/') -> rewrite('/');
```

but *it seems to do nothing at all* as I get a 404.

I've tried `-> rewrite('/index.html')` and `-> rewrite('/index.jsp')` to no avail.

The file is clearly being read, though, because if I put garbage into the file it throws an exception in the server log.

```
UT000045: Error parsing predicated handler string Invalid expression:
# path('/base') -> rewrite('/')
```

What have I missed?

I'm *quite* a neophyte to JBoss and the whole Undertow ecosystem; please let me know what other details I should add to this question.

## Curiosity

With request dumper activated, I see a single initial request to `/` made by JBoss (`User-Agent=Java/1.8.0_181`) immediately after booting, but when I navigate to `/` from a browser, I don't see that request in the dump. But I do see the failed request for `/base`. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm serving an Angular 8 SPA from /gui (like you my API is in another servlet). All I had to do with Undertow 2.0.15 (EAP 7.2) was add a WEB-INF/undertow-handlers.conf with:

```
path-prefix['gui'] and not file(%U) -> rewrite('/gui/index.html')
```

I would guess that if your SPA is served at / you could just:

```
not file(%U) -> rewrite('/index.html')
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know this was available. We've since restructured the site to use nginx in Docker, but this is far more elegant so have my checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

I had two problems:

I was missing rules, and I has misunderstood the function of `path-prefix` (which matches on complete and *non-terminal* path segments, rather than acting like a regex `^(group)`).

My final, working `undertow-handlers.conf` looks like this:

```
regex('/login(.*)') -> done;

path-prefix('/assets') -> done;

regex('(.*).js') -> done;
regex('(.*).map') -> done;

regex('(.*).svg') -> done;
regex('(.*).png') -> done;

regex('(.*).eot') -> done;
regex('(.*).woff2') -> done;

regex('(.*).html') -> done;

path('/') -> rewrite('/index.html');

path('/base') -> rewrite('index.html');
path-prefix('/shop') -> rewrite('index.html');


...and all my other angular routes
```

Note that `/base` is a terminal path segment, and matches with `path`, whereas `/shop/60` takes an additional path parameter, so requires `path-prefex`.

For whatever reason, the solution proposed in the linked question above, simply capturing it all with `path-prefix('/')` didn't work in my case.

Possibly-heplful side-note: we have a REST server that serves from `/RestService/` in another servlet context, so no rules were needed to allow that to continue to work.

Additionally, I was using webpack's development proxy server through ng hmr, and needed to add byPassProxy rules equivalent to the undertow rules, as well.

*I'm happy for improvements on this*: please don't hesitate to comment or add another answer.