# Deploying angular 9 app to Jboss 7 rewrite URL to index.html

Tags: angular, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy an angular app war file to jboss 7. But, I'm facing a problem; `404 page not found` in production build when refresh a page. I know that all Angular routes should be served via the index.html file So I must do an URL rewrite. I tried it in tomcat and it worked using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/dashboard/(.*) /dashboard/index.html
```

But I doesn't know how to do the same thing with jboss 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978074/how-do-i-configure-undertow-handlers-to-support-proper-rewriting-for-spa-bookmar

Answer (score 0):

By the help of Panagiotis Chavariotis comment (using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978074/how-do-i-configure-undertow-handlers-to-support-proper-rewriting-for-spa-bookmar)), I resolved the problem by adding this configuration file WEB-INF/undertow-handlers.conf:

```
path-prefix('/assets') -> done;
regex('(.*).js') -> done;
regex('(.*).ttf') -> done;
regex('(.*).woff') -> done;
regex('(.*).woff2') -> done;
regex('(.*).jpg') -> done;
regex('(.*).png') -> done;
regex('(.*).css') -> done;
regex('(.*).html') -> done;
path-prefix('/') -> rewrite('/');
```

Comment: I cant see why this means that : for every request index.html will be provided. Can somebody explain me ?